# Weird behaviour in React Navigation V6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am facing some weird behaviour with react navigation version 6.
When I have a headerLeft property assigned my headerTitleStyle doesn't work anymore.
So if I assign some value to headerLeft to place an icon let's say, my headerTitleStyle is not applying styles to the title, which is really weird.

home.navigator.js

```
 import React from "react";
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/native-stack";

import { ProductsScreen } from "../screens/products.screen";
import { colors } from "../theme/colors";
import { fonts } from "../theme/fonts";

import { MenuIcon } from "../components/menu-icon.component";
import { TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

export const HomeNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator
      initialRouteName="Products"
      screenOptions={{
        headerTitleStyle: { <<//Doesn't work when headerLeft is assigned.
          fontFamily: fonts.black,
        }, 
        headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: colors.bg.secondary,
          color:colors.brand.secondary,
        },
        headerLeft: () => (
          <TouchableOpacity>
            <MenuIcon height={52} width={52} weight={1.5} color={colors.brand.secondary} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        ),
      }}
    >
      <Stack.Screen
        options={{ title: "Marketplace", headerShadowVisible: false }}
        name="Products"
        component={ProductsScreen}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};
```

app.navigator.js:

```
import React from "react";

import { createMaterialBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs";

import { Ionicons } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import { colors } from "../theme/colors";
import { fonts } from "../theme/fonts";

import { Text } from "react-native";

import { HomeNavigator } from "./home.navigator";
import { CartScreen } from "../screens/cart.screen";
import { SearchScreen } from "../screens/search.screen";

const Tab = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator();

export const AppNavigator = () => (
  <Tab.Navigator
    initialRouteName="Products"
    shifting={true}
    screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
      tabBarLabel: (
        <Text style={{ fontFamily: fonts.bold, textAlign: "center" }}>
          {route.name}
        </Text>
      ),
      tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color }) => {
        let iconName;
        if (route.name === "Products") {
          iconName = focused ? "home-sharp" : "home-outline";
        } else if (route.name === "Search") {
          iconName = focused ? "search" : "search-outline";
        } else {
          iconName = focused ? "cart" : "cart-outline";
        }

        // You can return any component that you like here!
        return <Ionicons name={iconName} size={20} color={color} />;
      },
    })}
    barStyle={{
      backgroundColor: colors.bg.secondary,
      fontFamily: fonts.regular,
    }}
    activeColor={colors.brand.secondary}
    inactiveColor="gray"
  >
    <Tab.Screen name="Products" component={HomeNavigator} />
    <Tab.Screen name="Search" component={SearchScreen} />
    <Tab.Screen name="Cart" component={CartScreen} />
  </Tab.Navigator>
);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I guess it is because u have a StackScreen that is called Products and a Tab Screen that is called Products.

Comment: @yesIamFaded That's correct, now I changed it and it doesn't show me this warning anymore. Thanks a lot!! :)

Comment: yeah no worries have a good day!